# PHP get data from SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

I would like to get data from my SQL Server via PHP.

This works fine. Now I modified my query and get no results anymore.

**My table:**

```
ID | name  | bookingTime
1  | room  | 2020-07-08 07:27:58.350
```

**My query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable 
WHERE name = 'room'
AND bookingTime >= '2020-07-08 00:00:00'
AND bookingTime <= '2020-07-08 23:59:59'
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your query works for me... must be something more to it. What datatype is `bookingtime`?

Comment: What was the modification you made to the query? What did it look like before the modification? Are you getting an error message, or just an empty result set? Could someone else have deleted that row? Please post the table definition (`create table ...`)

Comment: modification: I added the last two lines. the datatype of bookingTime is datetime

Comment: You need to create a [mre] because what you have provided works [see dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c8f6b3c80472943ed2d1a3e2c91d5c5d)

Comment: Is your `LOGIN` using a language that isn't American? The string `'2020-07-08 23:59:59'` would be read as 07 August 2020 by SQL Server if `bookingtime` is a `datetime` in most other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit date format conversion is what is catching you off-guard here.

Repeating your table setup...

```sql
create table myTable (
  ID int,
  name varchar(10),
  bookingTime datetime
);
insert myTable values
  (1, 'room', convert(datetime, '2020-07-08 07:27:58.350', 120));

select * from myTable;
```

```
ID          name       bookingTime
----------- ---------- -----------------------
1           room       2020-07-08 07:27:58.350
```

Using `dateformat mdy` works as expected...

```sql
set dateformat mdy;
select *
from myTable 
where name = 'room'
and bookingTime >= '2020-07-08 00:00:00'
and bookingTime <= '2020-07-08 23:59:59';
```

```
ID          name       bookingTime
----------- ---------- -----------------------
1           room       2020-07-08 07:27:58.350
```

Using `dateformat dmy`, however, does not...

```sql
set dateformat dmy;
select *
from myTable 
where name = 'room'
and bookingTime >= '2020-07-08 00:00:00'
and bookingTime <= '2020-07-08 23:59:59';
```

```
ID          name       bookingTime
----------- ---------- -----------------------
```

You avoid issues like this by using Parameterized Queries with correctly typed parameters, or by using `convert()` with specific date styles...

```sql
set dateformat dmy;
select *
from myTable 
where name = 'room'
and bookingTime >= convert(datetime, '2020-07-08 00:00:00', 120)
and bookingTime <= convert(datetime, '2020-07-08 23:59:59', 120);
```

```
ID          name       bookingTime
----------- ---------- -----------------------
1           room       2020-07-08 07:27:58.350
```